# Time and size based logger backup policy

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback

I am trying to create logger policy in a spring based project.

In below logger I wish to created a rolling policy which creates a **new file when rollingfile.log exceds more than 10 Mb**. So I can have backup of logs without having one single huge logger file. Is there any way to do that?

Given below is my logback.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
        <property name="LOG_PATH" value="D:/coinLogs" />
        <property name="LOG_ARCHIVE" value="${LOG_PATH}/archive" />

        <appender name="Console-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout>
                <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] - [%X{requestId}] - %p %c -- %m%n
                </pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="File-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>${LOG_PATH}/logfile.log</file>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] - [%X{requestId}] - %p %c -- %m%n
                </pattern>
                <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="RollingFile-Appender"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${LOG_PATH}/rollingfile.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/rollingfile.log%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="Async-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile-Appender" />
        </appender>

        <logger name="coinPay.logbackxml" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />
            <appender-ref ref="File-Appender" />
            <appender-ref ref="Async-Appender" />
        </logger>

        <!-- To remove extra hibernate logs -->
        <logger name="org.hibernate">
            <level value="info" />
        </logger>

        <root>
            <appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />
            <appender-ref ref="File-Appender" />
            <appender-ref ref="Async-Appender" />
        </root>

    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total size cap is not doing what you want.

```
 <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
```

It caps the total size of all your archived log files. You could have a look at [TimeBasedArchiveRemover::capTotalSize](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/v_1.1.8/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/TimeBasedArchiveRemover.java#L95) to understand what it is doing.

What you need to do is change `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` to `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` and set `<maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>`

So your configuration should include:

```
 <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
     <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/rollingfile.log%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
     </fileNamePattern>
     <maxFileSize>10MB<maxFileSize>
     <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
 </rollingPolicy>
```

Comment: Hi @roby, SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy does not delete the 'date log folder' but only the archived files inside the folder. Is there any configuration to achieve that